# Making a bot delete its own message after a timeout

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

I am looking to have my bot send a message, confirming that it executed the command, and then delete that confirmation message after a timeout; so as not to clutter the chat.

Here is a code sample of my current command I would like to have it applied to:

```
exports.auth = 1
exports.run = (client, message, args) => {
  let num = parseInt(args);
  message.channel.bulkDelete(num+1)
    .then(messages => console.log(`Bulk deleted ${num} messages`))
    .catch(console.error);
  message.channel.send(`Deleted ${num} messages!`);
  message.delete(5000);
};
```

If I have no time set in the Message.delete(); line, it just deletes the message I sent. If the time is long enough for the bot to send a message, it just gives me an error.

Comment: Why wouldn't it delete the message immediately? You're not doing anything to delay it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the message that you sent to delete it.

```
message.channel.send(`Deleted ${num} messages!`).then(sentMessage => {
    sentMessage.delete(5000);
});
```

This is gonna send the message and after the message was sent it will return it so you can manage it (delete/edit).